# How to configure Django's "staticfiles" app to list directory contents?

Tags: django, django-1.5

I'm using Django's built-in web server, in DEBUG mode.

This is part of my `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/static_root'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/abs/path/to/static/dir',
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

If I access `http://localhost:8000/static/png/`, I would expect to see a list of files available in `/abs/path/to/static/dir/png`. Instead I get a 404 error *"Directory indexes are not allowed here."*

Now if I access the files directly, e.g. `http://localhost:8000/static/png/test.png`, it works.

I've already checked some answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Directory%20indexes%20are%20not%20allowed%20here%20django)) without success.

So, does anyone know how to configure Django such that the `staticfiles` app lists directory contents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
'show_indexes': True
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve)

Comment: @ArnarYngvason yes but it still works, https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5/django/views/static.py#L23

Comment: Meaning, I should explicitly add an entry in `urlpatterns` (within `urls.py`) for it? I'll try that, but it feels redundant considering all the `STATIC*` configuration is done in `settings.py`

Comment: In fact django doesn't serve it because in normal usage, apache or nginx do it... Cleaner to enable a feature in development than to disable it in prod.

Comment: 2.2 link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve

Answer (score 12):

Just for completeness since it might help others, this is what I did to solve the problem.

Following @Hedde's answer, I went to use `show_indexes`:

### settings.py

- Kept all the configuration the same (i.e. all the `STATIC*` variables)
- Removed `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` from `INSTALLED_APPS`

The problem is that I cannot specify the `show_indexes` parameter using Django's "built-in" method for static file configuration (via `settings.py`). By having `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, Django would create the static file handler with `show_indexes = False`, ignoring my `urlpatterns`.

### urls.py

Added the following to urlpatterns:

```
url(regex  = r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.STATIC_URL[1:], 
    view   = 'django.views.static.serve', 
    kwargs = {'document_root': '/abs/path/to/static/dir',
              'show_indexes' : True})
```

Comment: For debug mode it looks like `static('foo', document_root='/bar', show_indexes=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

Those files are not meant to be served by django. Show indexes is a configuration parameter of apache/nginx.

In production, with nginx, just add to the static serving part :

```
    location ^~ /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            root /var/www/static_dir;
            if ($query_string) {
                    expires max;
            }
    }
```

For dev environnement, Hedde's answer is indeed the good answer, but the display may not be the exact same than the one offered by your HTTP server. Don't rely on it's look&feel.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve ...

```
static.serve(request, path, document_root, show_indexes=True)
```